# reference for the greek word παστός as ritual coffin for initiation rites

Tags: greek, ancient-greek

In this [link](http://greek_greek.enacademic.com/127547/%CF%80%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%84%CF%8C%CF%82), it is mentioned in the introduction that one of the meanings of the word ΄παστός' is that of a "coffin for priests used in initiation rites in remembrance of the death of the god represented by that priest" (translation from the Greek of the link). 
It's strange that this meaning is not included in the numbered lists that follow (a connection with 'bridal bed' could be possible, but it's not at all clear).
So as I haven't been able to track it in sources available to me (e.g. Liddell-Scott),
I would like to ask whether the above meaning is documented elsewhere in the literature.

Answer (score 3):

No attestation here, but the comments format does not allow me to include this screenshot from Beekes,

[image]

but one may well imagine a well-decorated coffin for a ritual; so yes, the linkage to decorated bridal beds is not far-fetched.